# Hide default monitor message when turning screen off

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to turn the monitor off via my RPI, which works good with any of these options

```
vcgencmd display_power 0

tvservice --off
```

But then, with both of them, it shows a default message saying something like "Cable not connected". Is there any way to block it or hide it or use any other command that might not end up in the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning off, you can go for a blank screensaver

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

This provides many options for setting up the screensaver, or disabling it completely.

Comment: Do not answer off topic questions. Vote to close them instead. Answering such question is a disservice to SO. [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Rob I'm running this commands via python from my RPI so why is this an off topic question exactly?

Comment: @muilpp [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You are giving instructions on how to install a program on a raspberry pi for general purpose uses. That is not a programming question and, therefore, off topic for SO.

Comment: It is the way thru he can blank his screen. And yes, you're right. But I think he didn't know where to ask this question. And if he don't know, I don't think he should remain blank. At least he got his answer after coming here. Now he can move further.

Comment: I'm using this in a python script, that's why it qualifies as a programming issue to me. On top of this, the answer is perfectly valid and it might help someone else as it did to me. In my opinion, you are splitting hairs here...